# Binding a table to a row?

Tags: sqlite

Lets suppose there are multiple students and I want to bind a student with multiple courses and bind a course with a grade.

For example student "peter" has the course physics with the grade 3, mathematics with the grade 2 and English with the grade 1. Another student "jones" has the courses Spanish with the grade 2 and mathematics  with grade 1. And so on...

My approach to this problem would be to create a table for each student with the table name being the students name. These tables would have the columns "course" and "grade". Then I would have a Table called "Students" with the columns "id" and "name". I would have to assign each student id to the right table which contains the courses and marks for that student.

The problem with this approach is, I would have to create a lot of tables. So Is that the proper way to solve this problem in SQLite? How could I bind a table to one student id?

Comment: This should be tagged [sql], not [sqlite].

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I believe SQLite as per ***So Is that the proper way to solve this problem in SQLite?***. Perhaps the question should be more specififc?

Comment: @MikeT: The problem and the solution are independent of the RDBMS. It's a DDL question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So Is that the proper way to solve this problem in SQLite?

Not really as it then does not conform to normalisation nor does it utilise the power of relationships(binding) i.e. SQLite is a RDBMS/RDMS (**R**elational **D**ata**B**ase **M**anagement **S**ystem and therefore copes very well with relationships.

> How could I bind a table to one student id?

From your descrition you have two major components **Students** and **Courses**. Therefore you'd look to creating a table for each.

The **students** table you would include columns specific to each student and to cater for relationships a column for uniquely identifying each row (***see INTEGER PRIMARY KEY below***). Rather than a table per student.

So you might have a table with column an id column and a name column (plus other columns as required). e.g. `CREATE TABLE (studentid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, studentname TEXT);`

For the **courses** table you might have a similar table with an id column and a name column. e.g. `CREATE TABLE (courseid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, coursename);`.

You would then have a **mapping/binding/associative** table (many other terms can be used) as from your description there would be a **many to many** relationship. i.e. A student could be enrolled for a number(many) of cousres; and a course could have a number(many) of students enrolled.

This table would have two columns studentid and cousreid each being a unique combination (assuming that a student wouldn't be enrolled on the same course multiple times).

As you want a grade (I think) per course/student combination, this would be another column (as say could be number of lessons attended/passed and so on).

So you could have a table named enrolments (or whatever name you feel comfortable with) e.g. `CREATE TABLE enrolments (courseid INTEGER, studentid INTEGER, grade INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (courseid, studentid))`

- A note on **`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`**, this is a special column type it defines the column as an alias for the special (normally unseen) **rowid**, which will be a unique integer normally 1, then 2 then 3 etc. (Note you will often see INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, this is similar. However this is rarely needed (it guarantees a higher id but has overheads)) [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Using the above code results in three tables **Students**, **Cousres** and **Enrolments**

These could be populated, for demonstration purposes, using :-

For the **students table** :-

```
INSERT INTO students (studentname) VALUES('Fred');
INSERT INTO students (studentname) VALUES('Bert');
INSERT INTO students (studentname) VALUES('Tom');
```

- Adds 3 students (Fred studentid =1, Bert studentid = 2, Tom studentid = 3)

For the **courses** table :-

```
INSERT INTO courses (coursename) VALUES('English');
INSERT INTO courses (coursename) VALUES('Maths');
INSERT INTO courses (coursename) VALUES('Spanish');
```

- Adds 3 courses English courseid=1, Maths courseid=2, Spanish courseid = 3.

For the **enrolments** table :-

```
INSERT INTO enrolments VALUES(1,1,0); -- Fred enrolled into English ungraded as yet
INSERT INTO enrolments VALUES(2,3,5); -- Tom enrolled into Maths with grade 5
INSERT INTO enrolments VALUES(2,2,0); -- Bert enrolled into Maths ungraded.
INSERT INTO enrolments VALUES(3,1,0); -- Fred enrolled into Spanish ungraded
INSERT INTO enrolments VALUES(3,2,0); -- Bert enrolled into Spanish ungraded
INSERT INTO enrolments VALUES(3,3,0); -- Tom into Spanish ungraded
```

- Adds 6 enrolments Fred into 2 courses (English and Spanish), Bert into 2 courses (Maths and Spanish) and Tom into 2 courses (Maths and Spanish).
- From the courses perspective English has 1 student, Maths has 2 students and Spanish has 3 students.

The tables would look like :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

The following SQL/query shows how you can bind using JOINS :-

```
SELECT coursename, studentname, grade 
FROM enrolments 
    JOIN students ON enrolments.studentid = students.studentid 
    JOIN courses ON enrolments.courseid = courses.courseid
ORDER BY coursename, grade DESC;
```

It could be interpreted as :-

- *get each row from the **enrolments** table and additionally get the row from the **courses** table where the **courseid** in the **courses** table matches the **courseid** in **this row** of the **enrolments** table and also additionally get the row from the **students** table where the **studentid** in the students table matches the **studentid** in **this row** of the **enrolments** table, sorting the results according to **coursename** and then by **grade** (i.e. grade within a course)* returning the **coursename**, **studentname** and **grade** columns.

This would result in :-

[image]

Say you wanted the number of students per course with the most enrolled in courses first then you could use (student details are irrelevant so the **binding** is just between the **enrolments** and the **courses** tables) :-

```
SELECT count(), coursename 
FROM enrolments JOIN courses ON enrolments.courseid = courses.courseid
GROUP BY coursename
ORDER BY count() DESC;
```

The result would be :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well and I also actually understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to create three tables:

- The first one is **Students** table, containing all students info along with student id
- The second one is **Course** table, containing all courses info along with the course id
- The last one is the **StudentClass** (or any better name) table, containing the student id, the course id and the grade for that student